# docmd.transfertext using queryname

Tags: database, vba, csv, export

I'm trying to export only certain data from a table to CSV file.

If I export the whole table, it gets exported perfectly but if I try to export only the selected data, nothing happens. I'm using queryname for the data to be exported. I don't get any error messages, so I don't know what's wrong.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Well, so far my code is as follows..

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String, strQ As String
Dim Path As String
Dim CustomerId As String

Path = Me.TxFilePath.Value
CustomerId = Me.OpenArgs

Set dbs = CurrentDb

strSQL = "Select table.*" & _
        "From table" & _
        "Where table.[name] = 'CustomerId';"

Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("strQ", strSQL)
MsgBox CustomerId, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Export"

Set qdf = Nothing

DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , strQ, Path, True

dbs.QueryDefs.Delete strQ
Set qdf = Nothing
dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this the exact code that you are running, as you have a whole host of issues here with variable names being passed as literal strings. For example in `strSQL=` you're literally passing 'CustomerId' as a string, not as the value contained within the `CustomerId` variable. Later in the code in the `DoCmd.TransferText` you're passing a variable called `strQ` that is never defined, so you're effectively exporting nothing. You need to make sure you pass this as a string `"strQ"`. I would suggest using `Option Explicit` at the top of your code it will help identify issues like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String, strQ As String
Dim Path As String
Dim CustomerId As Integer

Path = Me.TxFilePath.Value
CustomerId = CInt(Me.OpenArgs)

strSQL = "Select *" _
        & " From Table" _
        & " Where Name = " & CustomerId & ""

Set dbs = CurrentDb

Set dbs = CurrentDb()
Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("strQ", strSQL)
Set qdf = Nothing
dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing

DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "strQ", Path, True

DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "strQ"
```